# How can I use CRC/CRC libs in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, libraries, crc

I'm trying to use the checksum algorithm CRC in my code (python), but I'm facing several dificulties.
I tried to implement a CRC algorithm by my own but it's completely bad, a file of 20MB cost me 10+ minutes to calculate the CRC, add to the bitvector and resolve the bitvector.

After that I tried to use some librarys but i dont know how to use them at all. Searching in the web I founded some examples that helped me to calculate the CRC, but i dont know how to add it in the bitvector and resolve.

Can someone help me? I just need some examples of how to use one library or an algorithm that really work to implement.

I tried to use the the crc8, crccheck, crcmod and pycrc libraries.

I'm trying to open a file -> transform into bytes -> calculate the CRC -> send -> recieve -> verify the CRC -> open the file.

My actual code:

```
import base64
import sys
from os import startfile
from mmap import ACCESS_READ, mmap
from crccheck.crc import Crc32

def codifica():    
    print("Digite o Nome.extensão ou Diretorio do arquivo:")
    arquivo = input()
    with open(arquivo, 'rb') as fh, mmap(fh.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ) as mm:
        crc = Crc32.calc((b[0] for b in mm))
        print(fh.read())
        data = base64.b64encode(fh.read()+bytes(crc))

        check = fh[0] + fh[1] + fh[2]
        if(check == 'C:\\'):
            D = fh.split('\\')
            auxname = D[len(D) - 1]
            Nome = auxname.split('.')
        else:
             Nome = fh.split('.')
    saida = Nome[0] +'LI-FI.' + Nome[1]
    print(saida)
    return data,crc
```

Comment: You can see in this link where written all about CRC http://crcmod.sourceforge.net/crcmod.html

Comment: What is your question, exactly? As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: i changed my codifica() function, now i'm facing another problem. In codifica, now, i'm opening a generic file and calculating the CRC of the file, but now i need to add the CRC to the byte-like file object and then encode in base64. I'm trying to do `data=base64.b64encode(fh.read()+bytes(crc))` but it doesnt work.